# Output HTML in JSON string generated by PHP

Tags: php, jquery, html, json

I have some PHP that outputs json.

```
<?php
$html = utf8_encode($gegevens['tekst']);
$html = htmlentities($html);
//$html = htmlspecialchars($gegevens['tekst'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
echo json_encode(array( 'titel' => $gegevens['titel'], 'html' => $html ));
?>
```

The output will be like:

```
{"titel":"Here comes the title","html":"<strong>Here is the HTML<\/strong>\n<br \/>\n<br \/>\n     And some more."}
```

And the jQuery/Ajax will be:

```
$.ajax({
                            type: "GET",
                            url: "content/popup.php?id=" + id2,
                            dataType: 'json',
                            crossDomain: true,
                            success: function(json) {
                            var titel = json['titel'];
                            var html = json['html'];


function ContentTonen()
{
                                // Div's legen van content
$('.popup_home_head_inside').empty();
$('.popup_home_content_inside').empty();

$('.popup_home_head_inside').html(titel);
var html2 = html.replace(/\"/g, "");
//$('.popup_home_content_inside').html(html2);
$('.popup_home_content_inside').html(html2);
```

And the HTML output is:

```
<strong>Some HTML</strong> <br /> Some more text.
```

So it will not process as HTML.

Can you help me out?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need not escape the html with htmlentities on server side.

Remove the `$html = htmlentities($html);` from your php file.

Reason:
htmlentities will convert

```
<strong>Some HTML</strong> <br /> Some more text.
```

to

```
&lt;strong&gt;Some HTML&lt;/strong&gt; &lt;br /&gt; Some more text.
```

which when included in html will display:

```
<strong>Some HTML</strong> <br /> Some more text.
```

Comment: How do I prepare the html for JSON then? Stripslashes does not work.

Comment: What kind of preparation do you mean?

Comment: When I insert the HTML directly into the JsonEncode it returns null. Because it is not valid JSON. With htmlentities JsonEncode accepted the string as valid JSON. But which function should I use to prepare the HTML to be valid JSON?

Comment: Please try this.
`<?php
$html = utf8_encode($gegevens['tekst']);
echo json_encode(array( 'titel' => $gegevens['titel'], 'html' => $html ));
?>`

Comment: So simple and so effective. Thanks you saved me!